# Automorphism with no square root

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Related to [Every normal operator on a separable Hilbert space has a square root that commutes with it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096901/every-normal-operator-on-a-separable-hilbert-space-has-a-square-root-that-commut)

Does it exist an automorphism $f$ in a separable $\mathbb C$ Hilbert space, such that $f$ has no square root?

If so, a concrete example would be useful.

Comment: Certainly yes for a _real_ Hilbert space, for example let $H=\Bbb R$ and define $T:H\to H$ by $Tx=-x$.

Comment: I should have mentioned over $\mathbb C$. I edited the question. Thanks David.

Comment: The shift operators on $l^2$ do not have square roots: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485259/shift-operator-has-no-square-root The proofs there should work for $l^2$ equally well

Comment: Thanks but these are not automorphisms

Comment: The shift operator on $\ell_2(\Bbb Z)$ is an automorphism. Of course it has a square root, and in fact it's normal...

Comment: Not on $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, such operators exist. This was proven by Halmos, Lumer, and Schäffer, *Proc. AMS*, **4**, 1 (1953), 142-149.

Concretely, given a domain $D\subset\mathbb C$ define 
$$
D^{1/2}=\{\lambda\in\mathbb C:\ \lambda^2\in D\}. 
$$
They proved that the multiplication operator $M_z\in B(L^2(D))$ given by $(M_zf)(z)=zf(z)$ has a square root if and only if $D^{1/2}$ is disconnected. This can be seen to be equivalent to $D$ surrounding (but not containing, obviously) the origin.

So, if for instance you take any disk that does not contain the origin, say $D=\{\lambda:\ |\lambda-2|<1\}$, then $M_z\in B(L^2(D))$  is invertible and has no square root.